# Check for process on multiple platforms?

Tags: c++, exec, system, spawn

I'm using Qt, QProcess to launch a process, but there is presently no way to use QProcess to check existing running processes.

I need a way of achieving this on multiple platforms.  I have an application name that I want to look up, if its running I want to get it's PID.  If it isn't running I will create an instance of it, this last bit I can do.

I'm working on a Mac and so far I've done the following:

```
pid_t pid = fork();

if ( pid > 0 ) {
    int intStatus;
    while ( (pid = waitpid(-1, &intStatus, WNOHANG)) == 0) {
        system("ps -A");
        qDebug() << "Still waiting!";
        sleep(20);
    }
    qDebug() << "Exit Status %d" << WEXITSTATUS(intStatus);
}
```

The above executes the command and the output is dumped in the console, I need to capture this so I can process it.

Also looking for a way to achieve this on Windows platforms.

Comment: You could have the process you start to create some named shared resource to search for. Qt makes such things platform independent.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, any directions on how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Posix systems, you could capture the output of `ps` by using `popen` and then parse it.  The `popen` part looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    FILE *f = popen ("ps -A", "r");
    char s [1024];
    while (fgets (s, sizeof (s), f))
        std::cout << s;
    pclose (f);
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wBwNAKmT6HAs8DjU)

Comment: Thank you, now all I need to do is detect if the system is POSIX complaint or not and implement either your solution or a non POSIX solution.

Comment: Can you use conditional compilation?  Seems to me the choice is Windows / other.

Comment: Yes, I think preprocessors is going to be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to go about this on linux or unix, but here is an example for windows.

```cpp
int CheckProc(const wchar_t* procName, PROCESSENTRY32 *procEntry)
{
    HANDLE hSnap;

    hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    if (hSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("invalid handle value %s", (char*)hSnap);
        return -1;
    }

    procEntry->dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    
    if (!Process32First(hSnap, procEntry))
    {
        printf("process32first failed");
        CloseHandle(hSnap);
        return -1;
    }

    do
    {
        if(wcscmp(procEntry->szExeFile, procName) == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(hSnap, procEntry));

    CloseHandle(hSnap);

    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
    const wchar_t* procName = L"process name";

    CheckProc(procName, &procEntry);

    std::cout << "PID: " << procEntry.th32ProcessID;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking now for a posix way of achieving this, that should work on all platforms.